# how to manage Session in Wordpress using custom login?

Tags: customization, login, session, logout

I am new to WordPress, i want to implement custom Login functionality using WordPress. I am using the following Code to create custom login,

In wp.config file

```
if( !session_id() )
{
   session_start();
}
```

In header.php i am using the following code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
```

and after fetching data to create session used the below code:

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['myKey'] = $row['ID']; 
 header("location: http://localhost/newwordpress/?page_id=2");
```

in function.php i have created logout function as below:

```
function example_logout() {

if (session_id() ) {
    session_destroy();
 }
}
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'example_logout' );
```

everything is working, when i refresh the page or move to any other page, session gets destroyed, please help me how can i maintain session using WordPress.

I have asked the same question on stackoverflow then someone tell me to ask here.. so i am just copying my question here.... please help me..

**UPDATE :**

I have tried the [php_wordpress_and_session](http://www.thinkingoutloud.co.za/content/20091012/php_wordpress_and_session), but still i am not able to maintain session on the page.

Comment: Before going any further could you please clarify why you want to do this in plain PHP and bypass WordPress Login/Session functionality. Also what is the end-goal you try to achieve?

Comment: @kraftner please see updated question

Comment: Seeing as you paid no attention to the last two people who said it, I thought I'd become the third person to say: There is no need for you bypass Wordpress' session functionality; and it is inadvisable.

Comment: Your updated question does not address the concerns of the three voices who spoke out against doing this: there's a better way, and I promise you PHP sessions aren't the way.

Answer (score 0):

First answer this question: Why bypass the WordPress login/auth system? What's the end-game here?

I would highly recommend against using PHP sessions to maintain user state in the WordPress world. More likely than not, a cookie will be sufficient.

For using cookies, you can use the PHP [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/setcookie) function to set cookies, and the [`$_COOKIE` superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) to access cookies.

However, cookies aren't great for all purposes, especially cases where sensitive or internal information needs to be stored. In general, any purposes where you just need to save simple user preferences or user state containing otherwise-exposed information (like post IDs,) cookies can be very useful.

Comment: please see updated question